# Listar últimos usuários logados (GROUP BY E ORDER BY)

Tags: mysql, group-by, order-by

Tenho duas tabelas (*usuario e log*), e gostaria de listar os usuários ordenando pelos últimos logados. Estou utilizando o `GROUP BY` para juntar os logs (já que um usuário pode possuir mais que um).

O problema ocorre quando adiciono o `ORDER BY`, retornando erro na consulta:

> Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'insidetv.log.data' which is not functionally
>   dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

**SQL:**

```sql
SELECT nome, log.data FROM usuario JOIN log ON usuario.codigo = log.codigo_usuario GROUP BY usuario.codigo ORDER BY log.data
```

Comment: Seria mais interessante, até para se adequar ao formato deste site, você postar a solução como resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para listar os últimos (de forma decrescente), basta adicionar a clausula `ORDER BY DESC`, onde:

DESC: Decrescente
ASC: Ascendente

Por padrão, a linguagem `SQL` utiliza o ASC (forma crescente/ascendente).

**SQL:**

```
SELECT nome, max(log.data) as last_data FROM usuario JOIN log ON usuario.codigo = log.codigo_usuario GROUP BY usuario.codigo ORDER BY last_data DESC
```

Comment: Diego, seria interessante que, além da resposta em si, você apontasse aonde estava o problema e também, se possível, explicasse como encontrou a solução. ;)

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de editar sua resposta. Se achar que foi exagero ou que não está correto, peço que edite novamente e fica  meu pedido de desculpa.